# How to Set AlarmManager For notification that has to be repeated multiple times a day and everyday

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, alarmmanager, reminders

I am able to set AlarmManager for alarm that is triggered every 24 Hours :

```
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,holder.hours);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,holder.min);
    Intent in=new Intent(Reminder_entry.this,Notificationservice.class);
    in.putExtra("name",holder.name);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(Reminder_entry.this, holder.pi,      in,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManageram=AlarmManager)Reminder_entry.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 *24,pi);
```

But i am not able to set it so it can repeat say every 6 hours a day and everyday .
My research says i will have to daisyChain alarms so if one goes off i have to set for next day . Can you help me understand how this can be done? how can i reset the alarm when it is triggered and my pending intent is processed because my pending intent is calling A service and i dont know how to Set Alarm in a service  .

this is my service :

```
public class Notificationservice extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  String name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent i=new Intent(Notificationservice.this,Notification_landing.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(Notificationservice.this, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder b= new NotificationCompat.Builder(Notificationservice.this);
    b.setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(name).setContentText("time to take "+name).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setSound(soundUri);
    b.setContentIntent(pi);
    Notification n=b.build();
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)Notificationservice.this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nm.notify(1,n);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently implemented a service with an alarm, too, but won't claim to be an expert so more experienced users may disagree with my approach.

In my service, I do most of the real "work" in the `onHandleIntent()` method which is overridden from `IntentService`

In your case, I think it's a matter of doing the work then setting another alarm for 6 hours time when you want it to run again. For example:

```
     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // do the work that needs to be done every 6 hours
        someWork();

       // Now create a new PendingIntent and associate it with an alarm for 6 hours time
       // This example uses the current Intent and replays it but you could
       // modify it if you need to perform something different next time.

       PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1234, intent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

       // Find out system time in milliseconds for 6 hours in the future
       long scheduledTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

       // Set the alarm. Note that this version is using RTC - there are other options,
       // read the docs for more info: 
       // developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

       am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, scheduledTime, pIntent);
    }
```

Note that I opt not to use a `Calendar` for working out the future time for the alarm - I think it's less awkward just to use the System time in milliseconds.

**Update - some additional comments**

1. From your code, I see you are extending from `Service` - I think it is easier to extend from `IntentService` as Android has implemented a lot more of the key functionality for you so that overriding `onHandleIntent(Intent)` is more or less all you need to do.
2. My answer above uses `AlarmManager` rather than `NotificationManager` but the principle of daisy-chaining remains the same, I think.

Comment: So when your previous alarms fires your setup this new alarm ? i mean my app is a medicine reminder so a user may have to take medicine every 5 hours say every other day .  Imagine today is monday so after 4 repetition i will have to reset the alarm to tigger after 48 hours and then every 5 hours  .

Comment: Yes, setup the new alarm after the previous one has fired.

So in your case, you will probably have to add some additional logic to determine if it's an alarm for another 2 days or for 5 hours time. e.g. maybe there is one alarm followed by 4 more every 5 hours and then one for 48 hours later (then repeat the cycle).

Comment: finally cracked it , thank you so much for your help . if i store the unique if of the pending intent , can that be used to cancel the alarm if the user chooses to delete a medicine ?

Comment: I haven't done that before but it sounds like something that should be possible, I haven't checked though. Take a look further into the Android SDK docs for [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), though - I'm sure there's something in there. Or else ask a new SO question relating to that if you can't find the answer you're looking for. Glad I could be of some help!